# c# populate string list with recursive directory path

Tags: c#

I need to populate a string list with **not empty** recursive directory path.

with this code i can get the directory path and the number of subfolders:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"f:\PAB\");
int directoryCount = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@path).Length;
string[] directoryArray = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I want to populate a new list string with not empty directories

I think maybe I can use this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < directoryCount; i++)
{
    if (Directory.GetFiles(directoryArray[i]).Length != 0)
```

but I'm totally newbie with c# and I don't konw how can I do this.

Comment: Are you looking for `SearchOption.AllDirectories` option? `string[] directoryArray = Directory.GetDirectories(@"f:\PAB\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: I'm not sure. Subfloders should be empty or not. Inside a not empty folder are many files, I need to take de newest two *.pdf for each subfolders. PDF1 and PDF2 are the same but in different language. I want to merge all PDF1s and PDF2s for each language. The results will be 2 big files. I want to recreate an index too, and to do this I can read the number of pages with iTextSharp. So I want to put only the "not empty" subfolders in a list.

Comment: could you, please, convert your comment above into the question? Since your problem is not in finding *directories*, but *specific files*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to populate a new list string with not empty directories

If you account non-empty directories as "definitely having files" then this could be an option:

```
string path = @"yourpath";
List<string> non_empty_dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                           .Where(x => Directory.GetFiles(x).Length != 0).ToList();
```

This will extract all folders with subfolders.

If you need only the top directories use the `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`.

If non-empty means "definitely having files or having subfolder" you need to include this filter also into the where condition:

```
.Where(x => Directory.GetFiles(x).Length != 0 ||
            Directory.GetDirectories(x).Length != 0 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"f:\PAB\");
            int directoryCount = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@path).Length;

```
        List <string> nonEmptyDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => Directory.GetFiles(x).Length != 0).ToList();
        int nonEmptyDirectoryCounter = nonEmptyDirectory.Count;
        Console.WriteLine("Directory non vuote = {0}", nonEmptyDirectoryCounter);
        foreach (string nonEmptyDirectoryValue in nonEmptyDirectory)
        {
            string fileFullPath = nonEmptyDirectoryValue;
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(nonEmptyDirectoryValue);
            var orderedFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf").OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime);
            var newestTwo = orderedFiles.Take(2).ToArray();
            var fullNames = newestTwo.Select(File => File.FullName).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(fullNames[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(fullNames[1]);

            PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(fullNames[0]);
            int numberOfPagesFile1 = pdfReader1.NumberOfPages;
            PdfReader pdfReader2 = new PdfReader(fullNames[1]);
            int numberOfPagesFile2 = pdfReader2.NumberOfPages;

            totalItalianPages = totalItalianPages + numberOfPagesFile1;
            totalGermanPages = totalGermanPages + numberOfPagesFile2;

            Console.WriteLine("Numero pagine del documento1 pdf = {0}", numberOfPagesFile1);
            Console.WriteLine("Numero pagine del documento2 pdf = {0}", numberOfPagesFile2);
            Console.WriteLine("Numero totale pagine documento IT = {0}", totalItalianPages);
            Console.WriteLine("Numero totale pagine documento DE = {0}", totalGermanPages);



            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```